# Umbraco - Mobile Phone Detect and Redirect

Tags: .net, mobile-website, umbraco

I am looking for a way in a umbraco site to detect if the user has a mobile device, then redirect the user to a mobile optimized page. I will also need the user to be able to force the full site if they wish.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 4):

IPhone alt page umbraco project

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/iphone-alt-page

Answer (score 0):

For Detecting a mobile browser in ASP.NET following link will be helpful for you. I did implemented this and works fine for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/mobiledetect.aspx?msg=3159071